# ERROR : syntax error, unexpected '$app' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'

Tags: laravel, charts, chart.js

> Found in  [consoletvs\charts\src\ChartsServiceProvider.php]

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC3i9.png)

Found this error.. any ideas ?

Comment: you have to put your code not picture

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear, it tells you that you are missing one `)` after your `$app` variable.

Try this :

```
public function register(): void { 
     $this->app->singleton(Registrar::class, fn(Application $app)) => new Registrar (
           //...
     ); 
}
```